# XCode Key Chain Renew my certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, certificate

Today my First certificate became 1 year old, when i they to run my app on a divice i got this message:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: ********** (********)' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

So i went to my `Key Chain` and i got this:[image]

How to renew this `certificate` ??
by the way my distribution certificate still valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go over to Apple's Developer Portal to retrieve a new development certificate.  Once you log into http://developer.apple.com/ios you then go to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section (look under the "iOS Developer Program" menu along the right side of the page).  Inside there, you can see your currently issued certificates (which list their expiration dates), and renew / reissue them.

Oh, and pay up on the yearly Apple Developer membership fee if you haven't done so already.

Comment: But i cant find a certificate with the same name of my expired one

Comment: Create a new one then and see how it goes.

Comment: Upload CSR file.
Select .certSigningRequest file saved on your Mac. where to get this??

Comment: it's a utility that comes with KeyChain access, found in your "`/Application/Utilities/`" folder. [Here's a tutorial for you](http://cookbook.gamesalad.com/tutorials/3/parts/12).